# How to change Owner and group name of folder using php?

Tags: php, filesystems, plesk, filezilla, server-administration

I am using Filezilla for accessing my website files.But some files/folders permissions are not allowing to change in FTP.because their owner and group name is different (i.e apache/apache).So I want to change it from apache/apache to xyz/abc.Any helps ?

Thanks

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Answer (score 1):

Try using chown function provided in php http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php

Comment: It does't work, because it applies to a file, not to a directory, to read the documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `chown` php command for this:

```
bool chown ( string $filename , mixed $user )
```

`$filename` is the path to the filename
`$user` is the user name or id
This function returns false, if the operation is not successful.

**More info :**

You can read more about this function here:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php

**Couple remarks:**

- You can't change the owner if you don't have permissions for that
- Some servers will not allow execution by Apache, if the file's owner is different than the Apache user

Comment: Thank you for your reply.But I have a root access.Still it not allow me to change permissions ?

Comment: If you have root access, that doesn't mean that the Apache/PHP stack has it too (that would be a very bad practice anyway).

Comment: So what will be the resolution for this ?How I can change permission ?